# Best way to incorporate a password expiration date within the password hash

Tags: javascript, hash, ecmascript-6, passwords, salt

I wrote a few JS functions that are based off of PHP5s [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) functions. It's basically just an easier way to generate a password which is hashed with a random salt, and verify said password, without having to store the salt separately.

```js
    function passwordHash ( password ) {
        if( ! password )
            throw new Error('No password was given to hash')

        if( ! _.isString( password ) )
            throw new Error('Must provide a STRING as a password')

        // Generate the salt
        // THIS MUST NOT CHANGE! If this value is not the same as what
        // passwordVerify expects, no hash will be validated
        const salt = randStr( 20 )

        // Return the salted hash with the salt prepended to it
        return salt + makeHash( password, salt )
    }

    function passwordVerify ( password, passwdHash ) {
        if( ! password || ! passwdHash )
            throw new Error('Need to provide both a password and a hash to verify')

        if( ! _.isString( password ) || ! _.isString( passwdHash ) )
            throw new Error('Password and hash both need to be strings')

        // If the hash isn't even the proper length, don't bother checking
        if( passwdHash.length !== 108 )
            return false

        // Get the salt from the password hash - first 20 chars
        const salt = passwdHash.substr( 0, 20 )

        // Get the password hash, everything after the first 20 chars
        const hash = passwdHash.substr( 20 )

        // Check the hash against a hash generated with the same data
        return makeHash( password, salt ) === hash
    }

    function makeHash ( str, salt ) {
        if( ! _.isString( str ) || ! _.isString( salt ))
            throw new Error('_.hash() requires two string parameters, a string to hash and a salt')

        const h = crypto.createHash('sha512')

        h.update(str)
        h.update(salt)

        return h.digest('base64')
    }
```

Heres an example of it in use:

```
    <!-- language: lang-js -->
    const hash = _.passwordHash( 'secret' )
    _.passwordVerify( 'secret', hash ) === true
    _.passwordVerify( 'terces', hash ) === false
```

I was looking for a way to incorporate an expiration date in the hash as well, meaning if a date is provided when the hash is generated, then a deadline would be incorporated within the hash (so not in plain text). Example:

```
    <!-- language: lang-js -->
    const hash = _.passwordHash({
        'password'   : 'secret',
        'expiration' : new Date(new Date().getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
    })
    // If ran within 24 hours of when it was generated
    _.passwordVerify( 'secret', hash ) === true
    // If ran later than 24 hours after it was generated
    _.passwordVerify( 'secret', hash ) === false
```

But I can't find a consistent way to include a date in the hash that will reject the correct password *after* said date. I was thinking I could store a hashed version of the deadline right next to the password itself,  but that wouldn't be too difficult to exploit.

Any input would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why? Just store the date separately.

Comment: With `password_hash` and `password_verify` you don't need to supply a salt, that is even discouraged, so there is no need to save a salt separately. But the functions are not secure, there is no iteration or other method to insure a minimum hash CPU time, see comment below for details.

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score -1):

Simply hash your password with the current time, e.g. :

```
function passwordHash ( password ) {
    const salt = (+new Date()+"T"+randStr(20)).slice(20);//make shure salt has const length (may increase length due to lowered entropy)
    // Return the salted hash with the salt prepended to it
    return salt + makeHash( password, salt )
}
```

So now the password is hashed with the current time, so you could validate the hash normally. To check for the time, you can:

```
 const salt = passwdHash.substr( 0, 20 );
 const time=+salt.split("T")[0];
 //range check
 if(time<+new Date()) throw new Error("Token expired!");
```

---

You might consider storing the time additionally, or creating tokens if you want third-party authentification.

Comment: **This is not secure**, there is no iteration or other method to insure a minimum hash CPU time.

Comment: @zaph i think thats not related to the question. youve pointed it out in the comments already, i dont think i need to repeat your advise in my answer

Comment: Password security is related to the question. Further I don't think yet another example of insecure password handling is a good thing, it certainly is not a good thing for the user whose password handles improperly.

Comment: @zaph nope. somebody needs to transpile phps implementation to JS first

Comment: @zaph and coming back to your first point: the code does not contain any hashing. It just provides references to the OPs code, which is directly followed by your comment. So theres no need to point out *hashing security* as my answer does not contain any *hashing*

Comment: The first line of the answer: *"Simply hash your password with the current time"*.